# How do Emilia's beliefs about dreams reflect on her in "The Magician of Lublin"?

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, the-magician-of-lublin

In *The Magician of Lublin*, Emilia tries to contact Chrabotzky, her dead husband, through a medium. She then realized that the medium was a fraud. However, she does believe that she had dreams where she talked to her dead husband, and that Chrabotzky approved of her relationship with Yasha.

> She ridiculed Yadwiga and the Egyptian book of dream interpretation which the servant kept under her pillow—yet she, Emilia, believed in dreams herself. After Chrabotzky's death, several of his colleagues proposed marriage to her, but her dead husband had appeared before her in a dream and urged her to reject them. Once he even materialized before her as she was walking up the stairs at dusk. She revealed to Yasha that she loved him because his character was so like Chrabotzky's and that she had indications that Chrabotzky approved the match.
> <sub>(translated by Elaine Gottlieb and Joseph Singer, 1960)</sub>

Emilia is generally portrayed as being an intelligent person, but this paragraph indicates that she's capable of holding two contradictory views at the same time - both ridiculing Yadwiga's dream interpretation but believing in dreams herself.

What does this tell us about Emilia, and how does this reflect her relationship with Yasha?